# C# how to use my adaptername.GetPosition(“some string”)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, position, adapter

In c# , When I do

'ArrayAdapter myadaptername ;

myAdaptername = new ArrayAdapter(this.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, MyList);

int x = myadaptername.GetPosition(“London”) ;'

Where MyList is a List of cities containing London say half way up.

I am getting x = -1

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong .

Comment: Without knowing what your "adapter" is, how it is declared, initialized, etc. it may be difficult to get an answer to this. "Adapter" is a pretty generic term.

Comment: GetPosition() returns the position of a specific object in the array.  You are passing in another instance of the string "London" which is not the same as the object contained in the array.

Comment: @Jason I have a hard time believing that two identical strings would not evaluate to true in a comparison... Due to string interning, it should not be two separate instances. Otherwise it would be really difficult to compare strings.

Comment: @RonBeyerHi Ron, I have now put the code right, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the type of your item.
For example:

`ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, values);`